# Drush commands in submodule

Tags: 8, drush

I have a module as defined:

```
parent
    child1
    child2
    ... parent module files
```

These modules install and operate correctly.  My question is regarding drush.  I want `child1` to have the drush commands.  But when I declare them in `child1` drush does not recognize them.  However, when I declare them in `parent`, drush finds the commands and I can use them.

Looking through the `drush topic docs-configuration` file to see what that might afford me, I could find nothing to tell drush to look at child-module folders.

And the drush documentation is.... lacking.

Is it possible to define drush commands in `child1` or must they be defined in `parent`?